# Passing parameter to PL/SQL procedure using select from database

Tags: plsql

Is it possible to define a variable as `current_scn:= 'select current_scn from V$database'` in the declaration section of a procedure. Using the one below gives me the output. But I would like to define it in the declare section, so each time it gets executed it will get the current scn. Need to execute the procedure based on the input. Is it possible do so?

```
  DECLARE
       currnet_scn VARCHAR2(500);
     BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select current_scn from V$database' INTO currnet_scn;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(currnet_scn);
     END;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it *exactly* as you wanted (if you could, you'd already do it, I presume).

But, you can create a **function** which can then be used in `declare` section. See how:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_scn
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    retval number;
  5  begin
  6    select current_scn into retval from V$database;
  7    return retval;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    current_scn number := f_scn;              --> function is used here
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('SCN = ' || current_scn);
  5  end;
  6  /
SCN = 16535194799153

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Though, now you don't need to declare anything at all:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('SCN = ' || f_scn);
  3  end;
  4  /
SCN = 16535194799171

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Your example uses dynamic SQL. Why? There's nothing *dynamic* in it, which means that

```
select current_Scn into current_scn from v$database;
```

works just fine.

Finally: don't name variables as column names; it causes confusion. I'd suggest to make it e.g. `declare v_current_scn number;`

Comment: @Liitlefoot thanks for your input got my answer exactly what i am looking for.